# How to extend an Entity with additional annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an JPA entity like this:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cd_user", nullable = false)
    private UUID cdUser;
    
    ...
}
```

It resides on a maven "model" module that just imports:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The design is to keep it very light (without importing many dependencies).

Then I have a business module that imports spring boot, which imports hibernate.

I want to annotate it with @DynamicUpdate to reduce database writes on unnecessary changes (the entity "user" is just an example, in reality it has many fields).

But i don't want to import the entire hibernate-core on my "model" module. Instead, I want to annotate it on my business module, without repeating the fields.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

as always it depends on what you want to achieve.
If you want to reuse your 'model' module in other applications without a hibernate dependency and you want to use the @DynamicUpdate annotation in your spring boot hibernate app you could subclass the entity and annotate the subclass in the spring boot app.
If you dont want the hibernate dependency in your 'model' module you could mark the hibernate annotataion as provided in your pom. Then your spring boot app should take the annotation into account and other components that use your module dont have an additional compile time hibernate dependency.

Comment: The maven provided is a good tip, thanks.